# pandas to_csv split some rows in 2 lines

Tags: python, pandas

i have a problem with pandas.to_csv

pandas dataframe work correctly and pd.to_excel work well too.

when i try to use .to_csv some rows splitted in two (i see it in wordpad and excel)

for example:

```
line 1: provincia;comune;Ragione sociale;indirizzo;civico;destinazione;sup_coperta
```

`line2: AR;CHIUSI DELLA VERNA;ex sacci;LOC. CORSALONE STRADA REGIONALE`

```
line3: 71;;SITO DISMESSO;
```

my code `toscana.to_csv("toscana.csv", index = False, encoding = "utf-8", sep=";")`

EDIT: i add some line with the problem
(thx to all for the comments!)

[image]
`
how i can remove line breaks in values? I found \r in a cell splitted in 2 csv lines: Out[17]: u'IMPIANTI SPORTIVI: CIRCOLO CULTURALE RICREATIVO \rPESTELLO'

i solve with

`def replace(x):
    if type(x) == str or type(x) == unicode:
        x = x.replace('\r', '')
    else:
        x = x[0].replace('\r', '')
    return x`

toscana["indirizzo"] = toscana["indirizzo"].map(lambda x: x.replace('"', ''))
toscana["indirizzo"] = toscana["indirizzo"].map(lambda x: replace(x))

toscana["Ragione sociale"] = toscana["Ragione sociale"].map(lambda x: x.replace('"', ''))
toscana["Ragione sociale"] = toscana["Ragione sociale"].map(lambda x: replace(x))

### there is smarter methods to do it?

Comment: can you include the first few lines of your dataframe in your question?

Comment: Seems to me that you have line breaks in values.

Comment: how i can remove line breaks in values? I found \r in a cell splitted in 2 csv lines:
Out[17]: u'IMPIANTI SPORTIVI: CIRCOLO CULTURALE RICREATIVO \rPESTELLO'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Pandas Replace method to achieve this rather than creating a new function.

[Pandas Replace Method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

It includes regex so you can include expressions in the replace such as `|` for `Or`

In the example we will use `regex=True` and replace the `\\` with a `\` using regex

adding `inplace = True` will change the value without adding / removing any data from the position in the table.

`r"\\t|\\n|\\r"` is the same as `"\\t" or "\\n" or "\\r"` and we replace with the single `\`

```
df.replace(to_replace=[r"\\t|\\n|\\r", "\t|\n|\r"], value=["",""], regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).